# How can i stop the auto lock functionality in wpf if i am using a long running child window?

Tags: c#, wpf, routed-events

I have a Auto lock functionality in my application and it is working fine

Logic I used for autolock functionality is based on this article

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42884/Implementation-of-Auto-Logoff-Based-on-User-Inacti

Now what i required is i have a long running printing module in this application. Because of this auto lock the process is pausing after a certain time. How i can i stop the autolock functionality when i am using the long running printing module.

Comment: Hi Jeevan, welcome to stackoverflow.
Inorder to receive best answers for your question. i would recommend to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is a *long running window*?

Comment: @SirRufo It is a printing window. it takes about 1 day to finish the process.

Comment: @Jeevan The window itself cannot print anything, it is code that will send data to a printer. There are several options for that kind of very long task. (f.i. let it procss from a service on a server)

Comment: @SirRufo I Agree that.But i cannot change how the printing works. I want to disable this autolock functionality only on this particular window while printing is occuring.

Comment: @Jeevan Please add a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)